# dataTable style (color, bgcColor, border...)

Tags: reactjs, bootstrap-4, datatable

How can I change the styling(color, bgColr, border,hover ..etc) of dataTable with reactjs
[dataTable image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/alLcI.png)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To change the style of reactDataTable you can override the CSS styles.

> CSS Overrides
> If you would like to customize the layout components of React Data Table using styled-components (e.g. styled(DataTable)), or your favorite CSS, SCSS, LESS, etc.. pre-processor you may use the following classNames:

- rdt_Table
- rdt_TableRow
- rdt_TableCol
- rdt_TableCol_Sortable
- rdt_TableCell
- rdt_TableHeader
- rdt_TableFooter
- rdt_TableHead
- rdt_TableHeadRow
- rdt_TableBody
- rdt_ExpanderRow

[Check the react data table documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@jorgeramos/react-data-table-component#css-overrides)
[Check a working stackblitz example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-datatable-example-bavnfz?file=src/style.css)